# INSERT INTO auto increment identity for a one-column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a table Person.

```
Id, Name, Phone
-------------------
1,  NULL, 123456789
```

This Person.Id is an auto increment identity. After a while, I found `Name` is useless for the current business and it always is NULL. So I deleted this column.

Later, I found one person can have multiple phone numbers. And since SQL Server doesn't support array type, I had to move this Phone to a separated table. So, there is just one column Id left.

[Is a one column table good design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951686/is-a-one-column-table-good-design)

I have enough reason keep this one-column table, because the Id is important for other tables (link).

But there is a problem for the INSERT query.

```
INSERT INTO Person(Id) OUTPUT Inserted.Id VALUES(DEFAULT)
```

The value either `DEFAULT` or `NULL` wouldn't work with the error message:

> DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

Leave the parentheses empty also doesn't work.

Comment: A `Person` table without so much as a `Name` column seems a bit ....... useless to me. Even if you have your ID's in there - how can you keep apart person #317 and person #781 and know who those people are, if you don't even store as much as a name for them?!?

Comment: If your `Person` table really consists of nothing but the `Id` identity column - you can insert values using `INSERT INTO dbo.Person DEFAULT VALUES;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `VALUES(DEFAULT)`, omit the column name and specify `DEFAULT VALUES` to assign defaults for all columns (only column in this case). Example with the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO Person OUTPUT Inserted.Id DEFAULT VALUES;
```